# Python in vscode( for beginner)

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

In debugging mode for python in vscode, whenever I press F11 or Fn+F11 to enter into a function, it doesn’t work. Rather it goes into screenshot mode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume screentshot happens because of your keyboard layout. To make sure you can check shortcuts for debugging mode or use cursor to use debugging functions. This documentations might help :
[Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Comment: Thanks. Will check that out